# How to disable/remove a tab from tabbed activity from android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, tabs

I am a newbie to native android development. I made an app in android studio using `tabbed activity`. By default there are `3` tabs in it but i want to remove/disable the third tab. What should i do? I searched many article on it but all i find is for `tabhost`.

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In FragmentPagerAdapter inside tabbed activity, change get count return to 2.

```
 @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 2 total pages.
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "SECTION 1";
            case 1:
                return "SECTION 2";

        }
        return null;
    }
```